# How to find origin of a apparently buggy LNK2005 (symbol already defined)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, lib

I'm trying to compile a src code of an application that have the libs stripped from the files.

I already downloaded, compiled and linked each lib the project needs but I'm having trouble with a specific one: crypto (https://www.cryptopp.com/).

I receive a LNK2005 (symbol already defined) when trying to compile. The exact error message is:

> Error LNK2005 "public: __cdecl CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::Enc(void)"
> (??0Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in
> cryptlib_5_65-v141-x64.lib(rijndael.obj)  IGC.GameServer  D:\MU
> Online\IGCN_S9E2_Emu\source\GameServer\PacketEncrypt.obj  1
>
> Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols
> found IGC.GameServer  D:\MU
> Online\IGCN_S9E2_Emu\source\Output\IGC.GameServer\Release\IGC.GameServer.exe  1

Apparently the linker is complaining that the type `public: __cdecl CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::Enc(void)` is being defined twice (in rijndael.obj - crypto lib - and in PacketEncrypt.obj - the project I'm trying to compile).

I already had fixed the LNK2005 a lot of times in the past but this time I just can't figure out what's hapening.

As I don't know what can be causing this error I don't know exactly what to share here regarding the code. Bellow is some code I think that can help but if you feel something is missing you can ask for more code.

**Declaration of the type being defined twice**
[image: Declaration of the type being defined twice]

**Problematic declaration**
[image: Problematic declaration]

If I comment the two lines selected in the second print (and obviously cut off their references in the code) I can compile the project without any problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommend replacing the images with an [mcve].

Comment: Don't post images. Post *code* and *error messages*, as *text*.

Comment: Error says clearly: You are trying to redefine `Enc` constructor.

Comment: Sorry for not posting a "minimal, complete and verifiable example". I can give any code needed, the problem is that I'm just lost about which code to share. The project is very big have tons of LOC. Any hint will be appreciated though, does the problem gives you any insight about possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

So you are linking cryptlib_5_65 to IGC.GameServer, but the cryptlib already have that function. I am guessing that rijndael.cpp actually belongs to cryptlib project, but you added the source file to GameServer project as well. Check if that file is not in both projects and if so, remove it from the GameServer.
Implementation should be only in one of them.
It might not be the case, but the lack of better info from you, makes it difficult to find solution.

I would post it as a comment, but not enough points on my side.

Comment: Hey @Anicka thanks for answering. That was one of my first thoughts though, and the type being defined twice is not defined in the project. That's why I'm so lost about this. I'm starting to think it's a bug. Can you think about other possible cause?

Comment: Unless you post more info not.

Comment: What kind of info can I give you?